# Is there any sample maven selenium project which has parent and child modules to know how the pom has been structured for both?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, maven-plugin, cucumber-jvm

I am looking for a Sample Selenium webdriver project in java which has parent and child modules to know how the dependencies, plugins have been structured on POM on both parent and child module.